# how to change the partitioned column datatype?

Tags: hive, bigdata, hql

[image]
Consider I have the below table:

**CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE sales (
id INT,
name STRING,
amount DOUBLE
)
PARTITIONED BY (CITY INT);**

In the above table when i try to alter the non-partition datatype, I can use below command

**ALTER TABLE sales CHANGE name name varchar(10);**

Same way when I try to alter the partitoned datatype of city column

**ALTER TABLE sales CHANGE city city string;**

**FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Invalid column reference city**

Facing above error

Can anyone help me with query how to change datatype of partitioned column?

Answer (score 0):

You really cant. You need to recreate the table structure.

Partition columns creates physical folders to partition & store the data. So, only way is to -

1. create a new table with new partitioned column type.
2. insert into the new table from old table.
3. drop the old table
4. rename new table to old table.

Answer (score 0):

to change the partitioned column data type in hive :

use

```
alter table db_name.table_name partition column (column_name data_type);
```